# Desktop & mobile site, same urls, how to link back to each other?

Tags: php, routes

We are in the process of getting a mobile version of our site up and going. For various reasons we are investigating the "same URL, different content" structure via User Agent detection. No problems there, we're comfortable setting a cookie depending on UA settings and using this cookie to determine what content/css/etc to use.

The problem is though, we want to provide a link back to desktop version from the mobile page, and vice versa. We don't want to just link to the homepage, but to the same page, just in the other environment.

We were thinking about making the links contain a $_GET parameter

```
<a href="....html&mob=1">...</a> //mobile page, user wants desktop, AND
<a href="....html&mob=2">...</a> //desptop page, user wants mobile
```

Then in our prepend we would check for the $_GET parameter, if found, depending on it's status, to set or unset our cookie, and then do a redirect to the HTTP_REFERRER (the same page as they were just on).

The question is though, does anyone know how this will affect SEO/bots?

Is there a best practice for serving different content on the same url, AND have a link to the other version.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE - OUR CODE FOR DETECTING MOBILE USERS AND THEIR CHOICE**

```
// First page load, redirect if mobile
if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile'])){
    // SCRIPT SOURCED FROM: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/
    include_once(INCL_PREP . "lib/Mobile_Detect.php");
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    // if mobile device, but NOT tablet (they handle desktop versions just fine!)
    if ($detect->isMobile()  && !$detect->isTablet()) {
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = 1;
    $redirectURL= ...; // code removed for sake of space and relevancy
    header("location:$redirectURL");
}else{
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = 2;
}
// Get the $_SESSION['mobile'] status by the $_GET parameter
if($_GET['mobile'] == "on"){
     $_SESSION['mobile'] = 1;
}else{
        $_SESSION['mobile'] = 2;
}
```

So, the mobile version has $_GET a get parameter, and using this and $_SESSION we can auto redirect on page load, and they can also swap between the mobile and desktop version without a problem.

Thanks to the input people.

Comment: User agent tracking isn't perfect; you will inevitably have issues. You should instead look at responsive web design techniques.

Comment: >> For various reasons we are investigating the "same URL, different content" structure << responsive web design techniques is a poor choice for our requirements. Not only is it horrible for webpage "bloat" for mobile devices, we have the need to display different content for our mobile users as the "same URL, different content" implies. But thanks.

Comment: Yes I read that. Responsive web design is certainly not bloat, and it can render different content based on screen resolution. It's unfortunate you are willing to investigate. Best of luck.

Comment: You cannot "render" different content using css media queries, you can only alter the display of it. It's all rendered there in the html code, the desktop version and mobile version, so the actual html code base is bigger than before! For example, we have a desktop logo and a mobile logo, using media queries only allows us to display one or the other, so both have to be in the code, and thus the browser has to download both. By actually using the "different content" model now mobile users just download the smaller mobile logo, not the desktop logo, and certainly not both versions!

Comment: The "responsive web design" model, while is certainly a good option for some (generally smaller) websites, it's not a magic silver bullet to cure all ills. Just because google pushes it as their preferred model certainly doesn't make a global solution. But thanks for you're time and effort Zachary, it is appreciated!

Comment: "For example, we have a desktop logo and a mobile logo " - I agree with your point, @user986541, but your example is a poor one. Logo is a great example of something that can be swapped out in responsive stylesheets

Answer (score 2):

'Technically' you're not using the "same URL" - query string variants are actually treated as different URLs by search bots.

If you're trying to manage different URLs for mobile/desktop users and want to ensure that Google "sees" the right version, then read the following resource: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details

Half way down is the explanation on how to use the `rel="alternate"` and `rel="canonical"` for exactly the scenario you are describing.

Comment: Yeah, you are 100% right about the differing urls, not sure what I was talking about in the OP... sorry, my bad :-s Moving right along, we've decided on the 3rd option in the link you provided, different URLs, different content. Thanks for the input Mick!!!